# JMeter: How to provide condition in Beanshell post processor just to log successful/failed signup

Tags: csv, jmeter, response, beanshell, post-processor

Scenario is: 1000 users signup at same time.

Now, if the response message in "View results in a Tree" is "1", its successful registration, 
But if response message "3", its failed request.

I would like to know how can I handle this in Beanshell Post processor.

OR

Is it possible to have csv with result of all registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
String response = new String(data);

if (response.equals("3")) {
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
}
```

Where:

- `data` - is an array of Java [bytes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) holding parent sampler response
- `prev` - is an instance of [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class providing read/write access to parent sampler methods and fields

More information - [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

---

NB: It will be much faster and easier to go for [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) instead of the Beanshell PostProcessor

Answer (score 0):

When you say response, what  do you mean.

You can do it like this:

- add a response assertion and use contains, fill in a regexp for the place where the code "1" is. In all other cases you will have failure

Another way to do it:

- use a regexp extractor to extract response "code"
- use a jsr223 assertion + groovy, and test the variable extracted value

Answer (score 0):

Well, why do you need a beanshell for this? You can extract the "response bits" you want to validate using a regexp and use an if controller by comparing the response bits with expected values using the deafult javascript option. In the following example, I am extracting a word from the previous response and taking a decision using if controller[image]